# I want to add up the number which is coming in the string.Can anyone please tell me the program in JAVA?

Tags: java

Example:
Input:
String s = "My favorite pet 43 is 12 cat 32 "

Output:
Number = 43+12+33 = 88

How can we generate the output?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far please?  We need to see some effort from you first.  It will get you friendlier and more helpful answers.

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Comment: *"How can we generate the output?"*  By writing code.  Try it, you might like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split --> parse --> sum it up

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String s = "My favorite pet 43 is 12 cat 32 ";
    String split[] = s.split(" ");
    int sum=0;
    for(String str:split){
        try{
            int temp=Integer.parseInt(str);
            sum+=temp;
        }catch(Exception e){
            //
            continue;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: Next time i will take care of that . i will post that also what i tried . sstan and Dhanuka Lakshan